# I have urine inconsistency problem. Should I continue reading the holy Quran if some drops have fallen in my underwear?

Tags: salat, wudu, quran-recitation

I have a urine inconsistency problem. Whenever I go to washroom to pass urine some of it is still left in my bladder or penis. After sometime some drops come out and fall in my underwear. When I read the holy Quran some drops of urine is discharged. Should I continue reading the Quran?